# why are the icons a dev dependency?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, package.json

[The instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons) for how to install Material Design Icons in a Vuetify app are

```
$ yarn add @mdi/js -D
// OR
$ npm install @mdi/js -D
```

The -D flag indicates that the icons should be installed as a `devDependency`, but I don't understand why given that the icons are needed to run the app itself?

Comment: Because generally what you deploy to production for an SPA is the output of a build process

Comment: No good reason. @jonrsharpe But then there can be no `dependencies` at all, only `devDependencies`. I've seen this before and consider it a terrible practice because the semantics of real app and toolchain deps is not preserved this way. I hate to break through a list of linter and babel stuff when I need to look at client-side libs

Comment: @EstusFlask that's true; given that _nothing_ would be in `dependencies` if you only included what's needed on the server side, and it can be useful to get e.g. `npm audit` results for the things that are actually going to run in your users' browsers, I have used `dependencies` -> "(some of) this will get bundled" and `devDependencies` -> "this won't" in some projects.

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your last question. I was just about to answer. Here's the answer: `h1 .v-icon__svg {
width: 1em; height: auto; font-height: inherit; }`.  It's going to inherit whatever `font-size` comes from parent chain. The `font-height` is only necessary if you're setting `font-height` on svgs or on `.v-icon__svg` somewhere else. If it's specified and applies directly to the icon, no inheritance will happen, regardless of specificity. Let me know when you read it, so I can delete this.